# Text in `\underbrace` isn't centered in Hebrew

Tags: babel, right-to-left, underbrace

I am using `babel` to make Hebrew documents, and I try to use the `\underbrace` command to put some information below an equation. Doing it in English works as expected, but when I do that in Hebrew, the text isn't centered below the brace which looks terrible:

[image]

Here's the code if you wanna copy-paste:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@RTL \@RTLtrue
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \underbrace{a^2 + b^2 = c^2}_{\text{פיתגורס}} \]
\[ \underbrace{a^2 + b^2 = c^2}_{\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{Pythagoras}}} \]
\end{document}
```

How can I make the Hebrew text center under the brace like in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit different name for the font, as it was easy accessible, but the idea should be clear. Adding `\null` or `\hfil` overwrites the changed settings.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

%\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
%\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David-CLM-medium}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@RTL \@RTLtrue
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \underbrace{a^2 + b^2 = c^2}_{\null\text{פיתגורס}} \]
\[ \underbrace{a^2 + b^2 = c^2}_{\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{Pythagoras\hfil}}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have used `\mathmakebox` command from the `mathtools` package to create a box around the Hebrew text to have it centered.
PS: The code is compilable with LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools} % Added mathtools package

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@RTL \@RTLtrue
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \underbrace{a^2 + b^2 = c^2}_{\mathmakebox[\widthof{\text{פיתגורס}}][c]{\text{פיתגורס}}} \]
\[ \underbrace{a^2 + b^2 = c^2}_{\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{Pythagoras}}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]